# How can I add columns in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

> Example:
>
> DRIVER_ID;TIMESTAMP;POSITION
>
> 156;2014-02-01 00:00:00.739166+01;POINT(41.8836718276551 12.4877775603346)

I want to create a pandas dataframe with 4 columns that are the id, time, longitude, latitude.
So far, I got:

```
cur_cab = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(
            path,
            sep=";",
            header=None,
            parse_dates=[1]).reset_index()
cur_cab.columns = ['cab_id', 'datetime', 'point']
```

`path` specifies the .txt file containing the data.
I already wrote a function that returns the longitude and latitude values from the point formated string.
**How do I expand the data frame with the additional column and the splitted values ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading, if you're using a recent version of pandas then you can use the vectorised `str` methods to parse the column:

```
In [87]:
df['pos_x'], df['pos_y']= df['point'].str[6:-1].str.split(expand=True)
df

Out[87]:
   cab_id                   datetime  \
0     156 2014-01-31 23:00:00.739166   

                                      point  pos_x  pos_y  
0  POINT(41.8836718276551 12.4877775603346)      0      1
```

Also you should stop using `from_csv` it's no longer updated, use the top level [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) so your loading code would be:

```
cur_cab = pd.read_csv(
            path,
            sep=";",
            header=None,
            parse_dates=[1],
            names=['cab_id', 'datetime', 'point'],
            skiprows=1)
```

Comment: is there a particular reason why you added skiprows?

Comment: because you pass `header=None` it thinks your header line is data, we have to skip that row so it doesn't parse it as data

Comment: but i actually don't have a header. that's why i used `header=None` in the first place ;)

Comment: So what's this `DRIVER_ID;TIMESTAMP;POSITION` in your sample data?

Comment: Just the description of the data set, but I agree it may have been confusing :P